# Esp8266 (esp-03) breakout

Tags: surface-mount, through-hole, breakout, esp8266

Recently, Hackaday is talking a lot about the esp8266, a wifi to serial chip. I want to use the [esp-03](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP8266-Esp-03-Remote-Serial-Port-WIFI-Transceiver-Wireless-Module-AP-STA-C-/141454423509), a breakout with half-hole connectors that has 2mm pitch. Is there a breakout board that can turn that half hole connector into through hole connector so I can prototype on the breadboard? Or do I have to resort to different methods? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Adafruit has a breakout for a similar module. It's currently out of stock, though. http://www.adafruit.com/product/2471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1: buy A PCB breakout**

If you're willing to buy three, OSH-Park has a made-to-order ESP-03 breakout board. 
[image: PCB design for ESP8266 ESP-03 breakout board.]

**Option 2: wonky header sockets**

This is what I use, because it didn't cost me anything, and it's good enough for prototyping. I'm using [female header sockets](http://www.adafruit.com/product/2672) I had leftover from XBee projects.

[image: 2mm header sockets soldered onto the ESP03]

**Option 3: The Hari Wiguna DIY breadboard friendly way**

Described in his [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBfCPHXtSSY), Hari came up with a good way to make the ESP8266 ESP-03 breadboard friendly by using scrap LED anode and cathode clippings, and a piece of perfboard.

[image: Hari Wiguna method of using LED anode and cathode clippings and a perfboard]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but maybe this can help someone who is just now looking at this question and wanting an answer. Yes breakout boards for the 03 are available on ebay. I just bought one and used my Toast-R-Reflow to mount it and so far so good. They sell for a couple dollars each. The seller (tomyuen007) I bought mine from seems to specialize in ESP-8266 moduoles and add-ons. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a breakout board for that, but you can easily solder some male headers to it:

[image]

The lower, shorter pins stick through the half holes, so that you can stick the longer pins in the breadboard and the board lies on the plastic.

Comment: The module's pins are 2mm pitch, so you can't put those headers on it.

Comment: @Austin I just wanted to illustrate in case the OP didn't know what male headers were. These are not 2mm, but there exist 2mm headers.

Comment: Yes, though good luck finding a 2mm breadboard. I think the OP is going to need a breakout board or needs to solder wires onto the pins

Comment: @Austin oh right, forgot about that. But there has been a question about _that_ problem already: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24324/17592

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2mm pins to connect the device to 2.54mm breadboard , not all legs are in 3 out but they not needed for my purpose(link to product in comment) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2671